# Didn,t work setTimeout in use from Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, settimeout

I use highchart to draw some chart in my site. I want to print all charts that are in one page, in one pdf page. for do this work, i use this link : http://jsfiddle.net/jim31415/q5Rzu/150/

this work correctly, and print charts. But my problem is that after print charts, this part of code didn't work:

```
 // allow the browser to prepare before reverting
            setTimeout(function () {

                // put the chart back in
                $.each(charts, function (i, chart) {
                    origParent[i].appendChild(chart.container);
                });

                // restore all body content
                Highcharts.each(childNodes, function (node, i) {
                    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                        node.style.display = origDisplay[i];
                    }
                });
            }, 500);
```

and after click on "save" or 'concel' bottums, i see an other page with '#' end of page address and content of :
[image]

that variables of this content are my codes variables.

How must i do?

Comment: tested it in chrome, and the timeout function worked as it should....

Comment: I tested it in chrome...

Comment: but does it work for you when you're on fiddle? I see your screenshot comes from localhost

Comment: The demo you posted works fine. Please recreate the problem or provide steps needed to replicate your case.